# More than 1 Dispform for List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0, display-form

I have 2 groups of people which should have access to different versions of a DispForm of a List. For 1 of these groups all links should be disabled and they should see the content with another masterpage.

Can i create a second Dispform and link one group to this custom page? How to accomplish this with SharePoint Designer?

Or do i have to stick with 1 Dispform and have to switch the contents by getting the usergroup? How can i change the masterpage in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create as many DispForms as you'd like for a list.  In SharePoint Designer, copy the existing Dispform and rename the copy.  Hide the default form on the page by setting the IsVisible and IsIncluded flags to false.  Then add in a Custom List Form web part.  Customize as desired based on your requirements.

Then through navigational control and or audiencing, point the desired users to the appropriate forms.  I do this all the time when I need to create User Views and Administrator Views for dashboards and such.

Comment: agree, better idea then mine. but just wondering, which form will be rendered for a user clicked on an item in a ListView WP? :)

Comment: What ever is set as the default for that content type in SharePoint Designer.  There can only be one "Default", but it doesn't stop you from having multiple.

Answer (score 0):

no more than one DispForm for a single list at one time. You can try to redirect user on a custom application page from a dispForm based on security group.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called [SPListDisplaySetting](http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/) available on CodePlex. It allows you to show/hide display field in a specific form (new, edit or display) based in which group user belongs to, however this won't allow change the masterpage for list.